# XMLSerializer - issue with UTF-8 vs UTF-16 Code

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8

I am trying to serialize a simple object (5 string properties) into XML to save to a DB Image field.  Then I need to DeSerialize it back into a string later in the program.
However, I am getting some errors - caused by the XML being saved thinking it is in UTF-16 - however, when I load it from the DB back into a string - it thinks it is a UTF 8 String.

The error I get is

- InnerException  {"There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode."}  System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}
  -- Message  "There is an error in XML document (0, 0)." string

Is this happening because of the two different ways I save and load the string to/from the DB?  On the save I am using a StringBuilder - but on the load from  DB I  am using just a String.

Thoughts?

Serialize and Save to DB

```
        // Now Save the OBject XML to the Query Tables
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(ExportConfig.GetType());
        StringBuilder StringResult = new StringBuilder();
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(StringResult))
        {
           serializer.Serialize(writer, ExportConfig);
        }
        //MessageBox.Show("XML :  " + StringResult);
        // Now Save to the Query

    try
    {
        string UpdateSQL = "Update ZQryRpt "
                     + "  Set ExportConfig = " + TAGlobal.QuotedStr(StringResult.ToString())
                     + "  where QryId = " + TAGlobal.QuotedStr(((DataRowView)bindingSource_zQryRpt.Current).Row["QryID"].ToString())
                     ;
        ExecNonSelectSQL(UpdateSQL, uniConnection_Config);
    }
    catch (Exception Error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Setting ExportConfig: " + Error.Message);
    }
```

Load from DB And Deserialize

```
    byte[] binaryData = (byte[])((DataRowView)bindingSource_zQryRpt.Current).Row["ExportConfig"];
    string XMLStored = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);

    if (XMLStored.Length > 0)
    {
        IIDExportObject ExportConfig = new IIDExportObject();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(ExportConfig.GetType());
        //StringBuilder StringResult = new StringBuilder(XMLStored);
        // Load the XML from the Query into the StringBuilder

        // Now we need to build a Stream from the String to use in the XMLReader
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XMLStored);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
        {
            ExportConfig = (IIDExportObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only way I have found to solve issue is when reading skip the xml ident line.  So I normally use a StreamReader as my stream.  After opening the stream I do a reader.ReadLine();  Then feed into XmlReader.Create(reader).

Answer (score 0):

John - thank you very much for the comment!  It allowed me to complete the code and find a solution.

As you noted - using a stream reader was the solution - but I could not read the first line because there was only one 'line' in my string.  However, I could use the line

```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, false))
```

Which allows me to read the stream and ignore the "Byte Order Mark Detection" set to false.

```
    string XMLStored = MainFormRef.GetExportConfigForCurrentQuery();
    if (XMLStored.Length > 0)
    {
        IIDExportObject ExportConfig = new IIDExportObject();
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(ExportConfig.GetType());
            // Now we need to build a Stream from the String to use in the XMLReader
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XMLStored);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            // Now we need to use a StreamReader to get around UTF8 vs UTF16 issues
            //   A little cumbersome - but it works
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, false))
            {
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
                {
                    ExportConfig = (IIDExportObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

I am not sure this is the best solution - but it works.  I will be curious to see if anyone else has a better way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to G Bradley, I took his answer and generalized it a bit to make it a bit easier to call.

```
    public static string SerializeToXmlString<T>(T objectToSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = false;
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static T DeserializeFromXmlString<T>(string xmlString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xmlString))
            return default;

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, false))
        {
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
            {
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
```